# E-commerce tracking with GTM

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, google-tag-manager

can you advise me what is the best way how to track each phase of shopping cart? I use Google Tag Manager.

To set a dataLayer to push name of product on the button click (for instance Next etc.)?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you should start from reading official documentation, since it's very detailed and answers your question https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#checkout